# How to keep leading zeroes in Excel 2016 text cell after replace (Ctrl+H)

Tags: excel, leading-zero

I have a few hundred cells with values like 0100234X. The cells are Text format, but after Ctrl+H, replace X with blanks to remove it, Excel 2016 remove leading zeroes as well. The cells are still Text format.
Any idea how to force it to keep zeroes after replace?
I have a workaround - to remove X in Notepad and then paste values in Excel - then leading zeroes stay.
I hope you can tell me how to make it directly.
PS. If i delete X with backspace in a single cell, then Excel keep leading zeroes.

Comment: I don't think you can in Excel. You could replace it with some text character. If it were just for display purposes I'd probably use a `zero width space:ZWSP` (U+200B), but you could use a plain `space` or a `NBSP` if you didn't need zero width in that cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with helper column (if your cells are in one column).

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"X","")
```

or

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("X",A1),1,"")
```

will both give wanted result:

[image]